# Excel file column validation in SSIS

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, etl

I tried to use the below script in VS 2010, I got it to run without errors, however it doesn't seem to read my column header correctly. May I get help on what I'm doing wrong? Below are my screenshots of the work along with the script used:

[image]

[image]

Comment: whats working / failing?  If you add a data viewer on workflow between collection and next stage, does it show data?

Comment: Hi Daryl, I used the below instruction to do it  [ITbrothers] (http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/02/ssis-how-to-validate-excel-header.html  )